# Integrating a GPS interface into my emulator

Tags: android-emulator, gps

I am trying to run a **Google Maps** app on my **Nexus 5 emulator**  target: **Google Apis (level 21)**

and am getting the following warnings and errors in my **LogCat**:

```
03-23 15:19:03.672: E/GpsLocationProvider(368): no AGPS interface in set_agps_server

03-23 15:19:03.691: E/GpsLocationProvider(368): no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update

03-23 15:19:03.691: D/GpsLocationProvider(368): final config = #Mon Mar 23 15:19:03 GMT+00:00 2015


03-23 15:19:15.036: W/Searchables(368): No global search activity found


03-23 15:20:52.486: W/OneTimePlayLogger(963): logger connection failed


03-23 15:20:56.171: E/MDM(1046): No Google accounts; deferring server state update.


03-23 15:21:21.435: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1295): Google Play Store is missing.

03-23 15:21:21.438:E/.AppDataSearchProvider(1295): Could not connect to AppDataSearchClient for onTableChanged, error 9
```

How do I integrate a **GPS interface** into my **emulator**?